# Query condition concatenation

Tags: 8, database

I can do this directly in MySQL ...

```
GEOID + '-' + NAME IN ('01005-Barbour', '01007-Bibb')
```

But when I try to do this using the database API ...

```
$query->condition("s.STUSPS + '-' + c.NAME", $counties, 'IN');
```

I get an error and it looks like it strips out the concatenation ...

```
"WHERE s.STUSPSc.NAME IN (..."
```

How can I make this work? Thanks!

EDIT: I tried this as well, but it never processed ... like it was stuck in a loop or something.

```
foreach ($counties as $county) {
  $cArr = explode('-', $county);
  $andCondition = $query->andConditionGroup()
    ->condition('s.STUSPS', trim($cArr[0]))
    ->condition('c.NAME', trim($cArr[1]));
  $query->orConditionGroup()->condition($andCondition);
}
```

A fix for either way would help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use [`where`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21ConditionInterface.php/function/ConditionInterface%3A%3Awhere/8.4.x) rather than `condition`

Comment: Thanks, @Clive ... I'm trying to format that with no success yet ...

$query->where('s.STUSPS+"-"+c.NAME IN (:counties)', array(':counties' => "'".implode("','", $counties)."'"));

That says that '-' is not a column. Also tried 's.STUSPS+\'-\'+c.NAME.

This definitely feels like the right path though, but the proper formatting is still eluding me.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could concat like `"s.STUSPS + '-' + c.NAME"` in MySQL, I though you had to use `CONCAT`...`CONCAT(s.STUSPS, '-', c.NAME)`

Comment: Well, it works, but CONCAT() is probably more correct and definitely works better in the Drupal where(). After that, I had to figure out the parameter array and found the [] syntax ...

$query->where("CONCAT(s.STUSPS, '-', c.NAME) IN (:counties[])", array(':counties[]' => $counties));

Thanks, @Clive!